# Unable to connect to a particular kinesis stream with Flink Application

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, amazon-kinesis

The flink application is failing on a particular input kinesis stream with message

```
org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.AbortedException: 
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.abortIfNeeded(SdkFilterInputStream.java:61)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:89)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.org.apache.http.entity.InputStreamEntity.writeTo(InputStreamEntity.java:140)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.RepeatableInputStreamRequestEntity.writeTo(RepeatableInputStreamRequestEntity.java:160)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:156)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.sendRequestEntity(CPoolProxy.java:152)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:238)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.protocol.SdkHttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(SdkHttpRequestExecutor.java:63)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.SdkHttpClient.execute(SdkHttpClient.java:72)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1323)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1139)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:796)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:764)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:738)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:698)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:680)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:544)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:524)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.doInvoke(AmazonKinesisClient.java:2809)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.invoke(AmazonKinesisClient.java:2776)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.invoke(AmazonKinesisClient.java:2765)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.executeGetShardIterator(AmazonKinesisClient.java:1396)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.getShardIterator(AmazonKinesisClient.java:1367)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.proxy.KinesisProxy.getShardIterator(KinesisProxy.java:381)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.proxy.KinesisProxy.getShardIterator(KinesisProxy.java:371)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.internals.publisher.polling.PollingRecordPublisher.getShardIterator(PollingRecordPublisher.java:195)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.internals.publisher.polling.PollingRecordPublisher.<init>(PollingRecordPublisher.java:96)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.internals.publisher.polling.PollingRecordPublisherFactory.create(PollingRecordPublisherFactory.java:86)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.internals.publisher.polling.PollingRecordPublisherFactory.create(PollingRecordPublisherFactory.java:34)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.internals.KinesisDataFetcher.createRecordPublisher(KinesisDataFetcher.java:496)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.internals.KinesisDataFetcher.createShardConsumer(KinesisDataFetcher.java:465)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.internals.KinesisDataFetcher.runFetcher(KinesisDataFetcher.java:592)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.FlinkKinesisConsumer.run(FlinkKinesisConsumer.java:392)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:110)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:66)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask$LegacySourceFunctionThread.run(SourceStreamTask.java:269)
```

However, it is able to connect to any other kinesis stream with my flink application. Any hint what should I look for ?